# How to write typescript definitions for library `enhanced-resolve`?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm working on tsifying [enhanced-resolve](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve).

#### [The new one](https://github.com/ts-webpack/enhanced-resolve)

I've done most of the job.

However, the structure of *enhanced-resolve* is a bit old-fashion. It's hard to write a definition for [the entry module](https://github.com/ts-webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/master/lib/node.ts).

How can i turn to the following style of code into to a  typescript definition (removed irrelevant code)?

```
// here is on key point, export assignment
module.exports = function resolve(context, path, request, callback) {
};

module.exports.sync = function resolveSync(context, path, request){
};

// here is another key point, nested export on a function
module.exports.loader = function resolveLoader(context, path, request, callback) {
};

module.exports.loader.sync = function resolveLoaderSync(context, path, request) {
};
```

**PS: 2016-11-5**

See the [partly transformed code](https://github.com/ts-webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/master/lib/node.ts). The **Only** job i don't know how to accomplish is the export things. Since the export code should use `Export assignments` for the compatiblity with webpack.

I just wonder if there exists a solution for that?
or i should change the export signature of the library?

Comment: What do you mean you have done most if the tsifying?, Have you assigned the types to each of the functions in the library?

Comment: @NahushFarkande *most* means that only the entry module is not done yet. BTW, types for those functions can be done easily. That's not the topic.

Comment: If you assign types for the functions in the library and then compile the code with the `declaration` flag set to true in your `tsconfig.json`, typescript will generate the declaration files for you

Comment: I know that thing, but even the compiler doens't know how to generate the file correctly. You can download [the repo](https://github.com/ts-webpack/enhanced-resolve) and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb (this is mostly true if you want es6/7/2016/who knows what they call it these days):

#### 1. Imports

While `require` works perfectly with typescript, there is no information about the return type. Therefore it's worth using `import`s

```
import * as ResolverFactory from "./ResolverFactory"
import { Stuff, OtherStuff } from "./ResolverFactory"
```

#### 2. Exports

It's just a much nicer syntax:

```
export function resolve(context, path, request, callback) {
  //...
}
```

or

```
export const resolve = (context, path, request, callback) => {
  //...
}
```

#### 3. Type information

Since you are working with **Type**script it's worth gradually adding types to your arguments, fields, etc. Unfortunately I can't help with this, since I have no context about what your code does. If it uses a framework or is a plugin for a framework, it's always worth looking if they have their own typescript definitions, which you can use yourself.

Comment: thanks anyway. But i'm afraid that your answer is not the solution i need. You can see more details from my updated question!

Comment: it's not really clear what the problem is, if you have issues with exports, see point 2 of my answer. that will generate equivalent module.exports to what you have currently and also enables type safe imports

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now, you have a function as module.exports, and you are attaching other functions to the function object. This is interesting indeed. May I edit your question? The bunch of other exports/imports is just clutter and makes it harder to spot the problem...

Comment: I know the origin code sample is fuzzy. But that's why it's hard to write definitions. And it has multi-level "sub-export"(like nested namespaces).

Comment: If it would just export objects, you could easily refactor it, but I don't think the `export` keyword can do what you want...